# When I remove get_header() from 404 page, my css doesnt work

Tags: 404-error

When I remove get_header() from 404 page, my css doesnt work.

```
  <?php
   /**
   * The template for displaying 404 pages (Not Found)
   *
   * @package WordPress
   * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
   * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
   */

 ?>

<div class="page-content">
    <h1 class="page-title"><?php _e( 'Not Found', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></h1>
    <p><?php _e( 'It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try a search?', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></p>
</div>
```

css

```
  .page-content {
   max-width: 300px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: center;
  }

 .page-title {
  color: red;
 }
```

Comment: Why would you want to remove `get_header()`? Your CSS file is linked in this header, so it makes sense that it is no longer working when you remove this piece of code.

Comment: I have link my stylesheet to function.php.


 wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());

Comment: Because I don't want the logo and navigation for my 404 page.

Comment: Then either write a different header for your 404 page, or include all the things that are in the header that are required for a working page, such as your `html`,`head`,`body` directly in to the 404 page template. Your "header" that is associated with `get_header()` includes way more than just your navigation. Check your `header.php` file to see what is included.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it doesn't. When you remove `get_header()` you also remove the code that loads the CSS files, not to mention that you remove large blocks of necessary HTML markup. The template you've posted above is very, very broken.

You've also left out `get_footer()` which will most likely leave your markup broken as well.

Instead of leaving out [`get_header()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) use it with an optional argument to load a truncated header file for your 404 page:

> Description
>
> Includes the header.php template file from your current theme's
>   directory. If a name is specified then a specialised header
>   header-{name}.php will be included.
>
> If the theme contains no header.php file then the header from the
>   default theme wp-includes/theme-compat/header.php will be included.

For example (from the Codex):

```
if ( is_home() ) :
    get_header( 'home' );
elseif ( is_404() ) :
    get_header( '404' );
else :
    get_header();
endif;
```

In your template, you only need `get_header( '404' );` plus a PHP file named `header-404.php` containing whatever you want to display.

Comment: Check my below comment. I have my stylesheet in function php

Comment: Exactly where/how do you think the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook fires?

Comment: I'll give you a hint: `wp_enqueue_script` fires on `wp_head`, which is fired by the `wp_head()` function which is in the header file that you've left out.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum template structure is:

1) get_header()

2) get_footer()

You can not touch this functions, this is a heart of each template/page/single/category...

Comment: Using `get_header` and `get_footer` are not required, you can call `wp_head` and `wp_footer` directly inside a template file.

Comment: @Milo It is a little bit wrong way to do that ;)

Comment: It's not at all wrong. [Only `index.php` and `style.css` are required](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Basic_Templates).

Comment: @Milo OK, and what you put inside index.php? I am not talking about template hierarchy, I am talking about template functions :)

Comment: `get_header` and `get_footer` load templates. As I said in my first comment, you only need `wp_head` and `wp_footer`.